# C code compiled as framework for iOS 8 application crashes randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, c

I have compiled library code written in C as framework and using it in my iOS 8 application. I am directly calling API from this framework in my code written in objective-c, as in obj-c we can directly call c functions. But this framework crashes randomly. Earlier with iOS 7 this framework was working seamlessly, there was no such issue observed. So, I compiled it with SDK 8.0, but is still crashes randomly.

I hope someone might have solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors are you getting? And what code is causing those errors?

Comment: with ios 7 this was working fine. So here can you take compiled library for ios7 and include it in your ios8 project and run.? if it is posible from IOS development point of view then try that one

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a real solution can be suggested without more information. Run the app in the simulator or on a device, and when a crash  happens, Xcode will show you a traceback. That should tell you where the crash is happening, or at least give you some clues.

Report that information back here and maybe we can help :)